# How to reference an Image within quotation marks in HTML

Tags: html, image, reference, quotation-marks

I was wondering how to display an image inside of a button.

I have this code:

```
<input type="button" value="TEXT GOES HERE" onclick="showImage();"/>
```

And I wish to place an image within the button instead of text. I tried setting the value field to the path of the image:

```
<input type="button" value="this.src='Images/pickups.png'" onclick="showImage();"/>
```

but instead of displaying the image it simply displays the `this.src...` as text.

Comment: What do you exactly want ?

Comment: So I have a button on screen, and instead of having text inside the button I wish to put an image.

Comment: You need to create an `<img>` or use `<input type="image">`

Comment: I see no reason why you can't use `background-image: `...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `button`, use `button` html tag, and inside put `img`tag with `src` attribute pointing to your image url

```html
<button type="button"  onclick="showImage();"><img src="favicon.ico"/></button>
```